# Value Not loading in Dialog

Tags: aem, aem-6

I am facing a wierd issue wherein the value is available in the jcr (as i see it in crxde) but it is not loading in the page properties dialog. When the dialog loads i could see an error in the console - attaching the screencrab of the same.

[image]

I am an AEM6.0 with SP3, has anyone faced this issue before or any thoughts?

Regards,
Jayapal.S

Comment: You need to provide more information. Did you identify which widget/property is broken?

Comment: How are you reading the data?